# Password hashing with Salt in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, frameworks

Hello I'm facing some problems with the authentification mechanism provided by Spring Boot Security

The main issue is that I have a login form provided by Spring Boot Security and want to check the inputs with an underlying database of users with email, hashed_password, and user_salt

I injected my `UserDetailService` in the `WebSecurityConfigAdapter`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(as);  // @Autowired private AuthService as;
    }
```

The AuthService is the following:

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MyUserClassRepository ur;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        MyUserClass user = ur.findUserByEmail(username);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        System.out.println("User found but we must check the password");
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
    }

    @SessionScope
    public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

        private MyUserClass user;


        MyUserClass getUser(){
            return user; // I need to retrieve the user later for my Webapplication
        }

        MyUserPrincipal(MyUserClass user){
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            System.out.println("Call Granted");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return user.passwordHash;
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return user.email;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I need a hook or a method where I can get the input of the user so I can encode and salt the password.
A default PassWordEncoder as a component doesn't have access to the inputs or at least I don't know how to get the credentials in the input field:

```
//@Component
public final class myPwEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            System.out.println("Encode My Stuff: " + rawPassword);
            //MyUserClass user = ((AuthService.MyUserPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser(); NullPointerException because the User will be after the verification initialized...

            return rawPassword.toString();
        }

        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            System.out.println("Macthes call: "+rawPassword + " " + encodedPassword);
            return rawPassword.toString().equals(encodedPassword);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help!
(I want to use sha256-hash with random generated Salt stored in the user DB table. I know BCrypt is probably the best choice but I have to need to use sha256)

Comment: this is for basic authentication, right?

Comment: Yes its a simple Webproject to learn Spring Boot and WebServices in Java. With a protected Route which i will configure later.